# Dictionary for three data values per set

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I am trying to write a code that sorts movie by title, Id and genre. But as of right now I can only figure out to use a dictionary that only stores 2, key and value. is there anything else I can do?

```
import csv

dict_from_csv = {}

with open('movies_20.csv', 'r') as inp:
    reader = csv.reader(inp)
    dict_from_csv = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}

print(dict_from_csv)
```

#This sorts it out for my first two, which are ID and Title. but I can't figure out how to make it 3.

Comment: Dictionaries are a key-value data structure, so inherently won't work for what you're asking for. As you did not provide a proper example of what the data looks like, it's hard to deduct what is the expected behavior you're looking for. E.g. do you sort first for the title, then id, then genre, but how is that supposed to work exactly? if you sort the title then you shuffle the id and genre, if you sort fo id you shuffle the other two. Please give some example

Comment: please provide example of the data:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Since you mention `movies.csv` I would assume something like `10,Terminator,1992,Arnold,Los Angeles,...`. If you need multiple sorting fields, a dictionary may be wrong for you. How about an in-memory SQLite ?